# Blazor how to integrate a remote js script that emit content

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have to integrate in a Blazor server page a JS script that emit some content (eg. it displays a cookie or a privacy policy)

It is not a script that I have to put in the _host.cshtml (in the head or in the bottom of body) but just a script to be put in a middle of a page (razor component)

Something like

```
<script id="CookieDeclaration" src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/0000-000-000/cd.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

I know how to InvokeAsync or InvokeVoidAsync with IJSRuntime a custom function, but I cannot figure out how to call this type of remote scripts

Thanks